# How do I get the bash debugger to work with ddd?

Tags: bash, debug

ddd script.bsh does not open the script. It shows an our glass and if I want to close ddd, it says "bash is busy"...

I found an old message, but it didn't help.
https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/ddd/2008-10/msg00006.html

I couldn't find ddd-3.3.12-test6.tar.gz, therefore I am using the ddd version from ubuntu repository. Also bashdb is already installed. Used apt-get install ddd bashdb.

Anyone able to use ddd for bash on Precise?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to get `ddd` and `bashdb` to play nice on Ubuntu 12.04 today:

1. Remove the repo-supplied `ddd`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove ddd
   ```
2. Fetch `ddd` v3.3.9 and install from source, e. g.:

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep ddd
   sudo apt-get install libmotif-dev
   wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/ddd/ddd-3.3.9.tar.gz
   tar xvf ddd-3.3.9.tar.gz
   cd ddd-3.3.9
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

   **Note:** I had to make a single patch to the source code to get the build to work -- in `ddd/strclass.C`, we needed a `#include <stdio.h>`; at the top to define `EOF`.
3. Make sure `bashdb` is installed:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install bashdb
   ```
4. Launch with:

   ```
   ddd --debugger /usr/bin/bashdb -- {script name} {parameters}
   ```

Could not live without ddd + Bash.

#### Optional: gpg verification:

Search for sign on https://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/ will redirect to https://savannah.gnu.org/project/memberlist-gpgkeys.php?group=ddd

1. Download `ddd-keyring.gpg`.
2. Import it into your key chain:

   ```
   gpg --import ddd-keyring.gpg
   ```
3. Verify the signature:

   ```
   wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/ddd/ddd-3.3.9.tar.gz.sig
   gpg --verify
   ```

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 4):

To get `ddd` to work with the bash debugger on bash scripts, it's necessary to install `bashdb` too.

If it's not installed, you get:

[image]

Afterwards, `ddd` seems to work normally:

[image]

Comment: bashdb is already installed and working. Did you get ddd running on precise?

Comment: @JamesMitch, yes, I'm on Precise 12.04 (64-bit, though).

Comment: Did you actually test to step through a bash script? I booted the Precise 12.04 64-bit DVD, installed ddd and bashdb and still couldn't open a bash script without seeing the hourglass.

Comment: I did get it working on Ubuntu 12.04, by using an old version of ddd (3.3.9).   Had to build it from source, and install the libmotif-dev package first.

Comment: Additional details here: http://askubuntu.com/a/178692/73165

Comment: Just followed your instructions on 12.04 / 64.  Almost works.  After bashdb loads the script I click "step" and go into an infinite wait for bash to finish starting.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is a regression introduced in *DDD* 3.3.12, see [bug #41649](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?41649).

The last usable version is 3.3.11.

Comment: Your bug report is from April 2014. The OP's question is from June 2012.

Comment: I’ve checked all four versions from 3.3.9 to 3.3.12. There’s definely a regression introduced in 3.3.12 (they’ve made lots of changes related to `remake`, `bashdb` and `pydb`). And 3.3.12 was released in 2009, so there’s a pretty good chance the OP was running this very version.

Comment: OK but this is the year 2018. An answer was written and accepted in 2012. Plus the answer received 4 up-votes.  The OP hasn't signed on in over five years an is unlikely to comment on your answer.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Okay, maybe mine is the answer to a slightly different question, but this page appears in Google's top 10 for those seeking the answer to "why `bashdb` integration doesn't work". So I'm not expecting any comments or upvotes, just accumulating the knowledge.